# Extract substring in R using grepl

Tags: r, string, dataframe, substring

I have a table with a string column formatted like this

```
abcdWorkstart.csv
abcdWorkcomplete.csv
```

And I would like to extract the last word in that filename. So I think the beginning pattern would be the word "Work" and ending pattern would be ".csv". I wrote something using grepl but not working.

```
grepl("Work{*}.csv", data$filename)
```

Basically I want to extract whatever between Work and .csv

**desired outcome:**

```
start
complete
```

Comment: please have a look at my edit @ajax2000. It's always a good practice to add the desired outcome to your question. This makes everything so much easier and ppl know exactly what you want. I encourage you to do this in your next question ;-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as an alternative way, remove everything you don't want.

```
x <- c("abcdWorkstart.csv", "abcdWorkcomplete.csv")

gsub("^.*Work|\\.csv$", "", x)
#[1] "start"    "complete"
```

please note:
 I have to use `gsub`. Because I first remove `^.*Work` then `\\.csv$`.

---

For `[\\s\\S]` or `\\d\\D` ...  (does not work with [g]?sub)

https://regex101.com/r/wFgkgG/1

Works with akruns approach:

`regmatches(v1, regexpr("(?<=Work)[\\s\\S]+(?=[.]csv)", v1, perl = T))`

```
str1<-
'12
.2
12'

gsub("[^.]","m",str1,perl=T)
gsub(".","m",str1,perl=T)
gsub(".","m",str1,perl=F)
```

`.` matches also `\n` when using the R engine.

Comment: pretty much all the solutions work, but i think this is more concise. thanks

Answer (score 10):

I think you need `sub` or `gsub` (substitute/extract) instead of `grepl` (find if match exists). Note that when not found, it will return the entire string unmodified:

```
fn <- c('abcdWorkstart.csv', 'abcdWorkcomplete.csv', 'abcdNothing.csv')
out <- sub(".*Work(.*)\\.csv$", "\\1", fn)
out
# [1] "start"           "complete"        "abcdNothing.csv"
```

You can work around this by filtering out the unchanged ones:

```
out[ out != fn ]
# [1] "start"    "complete"
```

Or marking them invalid with `NA` (or something else):

```
out[ out == fn ] <- NA
out
# [1] "start"    "complete" NA
```

Answer (score 7):

With `str_extract` from `stringr`. This uses positive lookarounds to match any character one or more times (.+) between "Work" and ".csv":

```
x <- c("abcdWorkstart.csv", "abcdWorkcomplete.csv")

library(stringr)
str_extract(x, "(?<=Work).+(?=\\.csv)")
# [1] "start"    "complete"
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is an option using `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R`.  Using a regex lookaround to match all characters that are not a `.` after the string 'Work', extract with `regmatches`

```
regmatches(v1, regexpr("(?<=Work)[^.]+(?=[.]csv)", v1, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "start"    "complete"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c('abcdWorkstart.csv', 'abcdWorkcomplete.csv', 'abcdNothing.csv')
```

Comment: To be more precise, you can use `"(?<=Work).*(?=.csv)"`.

Comment: @avid_useR  But, I am using `regmatches/regexpr`

Comment: (Correction: the perl regex extension allows for lookahead/behind, as used here, and I had thought that it did not allow embedded patterns such as character classes `[abc]` or any-char `.`. That is incorrect. So to be accurate/complete, my suggested pattern should be `"(?<=Work).*(?=\\.csv)"`, as @avid_useR has in that answer. Which is effectively what I had in my answer 4.5min earlier :-)

Comment: @AndreElrico, doesn't `[\\s\\S]` match *any character*? Isn't is more concise to use `.`?

Comment: @akrun, besides the aesthetics of backslashes (which can make my eyes bleed in extreme examples), is there an advantage to use `[.]` over `\\.`? It's not code-golf ...

Comment: @r2evans  I use both `[.]` or `\\.`, though I feel easier to type the former.

Comment: @AndreElrico Sure the dot does not match line breaks, but in this context, there wouldn't be any line breaks (they are file names afterall). So it **does** match everything between "Work" and ".csv"

Comment: @AndreElrico, I would have been surprised if there were line terminators in filenames ... (I'm having a hard time wondering how ext4, btrfs, and ntfs would deal with them, if I could even get them to work ...). Ok, so I see that `grepl("[\\s\\S]", "\n")` is false whereas `grepl(".", "\n")` it is true, I didn't realize that, thanks. Learn something new every day ...

Comment: @r2evans I just made a little note to my answer. Of course im just fooling around :-)

Comment: using the `.` is absolutely fine when dealing with filenames.

Comment: One gotcha with this (and the others, too) approach is that `regmatches(...)` does not necessarily match the indices of the original vector. For instance, three filenames entered, two came out, but there's not direct indication to which they belonged. (Not hard to determine with another line or two of code, and not unique to `regmatches` ... though my answer's returns with `NA` is unambiguous.)